# How to show pop-up?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have a windows service and form application. I have the installed service and both codes are correct.

But my problem is, when I run my service it generates a dialog of

> View the message or Ask me later dialog box

When I select first option of 'View the message' then it shows my Form Application.

I know this is generated because of **Interactive Service Detection**. But when I disabled IDS from services, and then I try to run my service then it doesn't show my Form Application?

Comment: try using  applying user authentication in service.

Answer (score 0):

If your services runs under the LOCALSYSTEM account then you can check "Allow service to interact with desktop", for the benefit of legacy services that would fail if they could not show UI. But it won't help you anyway because the UI will show in session 0 where it is never seen!

http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/system/sysinternals/session0changes.mspx

good worth of read.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-and-bit-Archite

Comment: Thanks for reply but I don't understand your 1st link. Please help

Comment: Windows has made some session system in Vista onward where Running windows services cannot access windows UI. therefore you need to know the implect of session system.

Comment: Last question, I am unable to get pop-up in windows server 2003 for the same application. Can you please  explain me the reason?

Comment: Simple answer is use userid and password with your service to show dialog box

Comment: I am saying it not showing pop up as I start Windows Service on Windows Server 2003